# Securely checking the origin of a message posted from another window

Tags: javascript, security, sendmessage, postmessage, web-application-security

My client-side code is receiving a message from another window (an iframe) -- something like this (let's call this `page1`, or `https://my.site/page1`):

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== ALLOWED_ORIGIN) {
        return;
    }
    // Further logic here
});
```

The iframe is expected to point to another URL on the same origin as `page1`, e.g. `https://my.site/page2`, where at a certain point, `page2` client JS executes:

```js
window.top.postMessage(somePayload);
```

My goal is to ensure that no matter where the iframe ends up pointing (perhaps due to an exploited vulnerability that I didn't notice), my `page1` only accepts messages sent from a URL on my domain.

I am thinking of using `window.origin` as `ALLOWED_ORIGIN` on `page1`. It seems easier than having to pass my domain itself from some sort of a config file that I'd have to change for all the different dev, testing environments, and ultimately, prod.

However, I can't find examples from others using this approach, and neither can I find any explanation of why it isn't good enough.

Is `event.origin !== window.origin` considered not secure enough, and most importantly, why?

My apologies if this is something obvious, and thanks for reading this question!

Comment: Well, just to see what would happen, I opened my browser console on this page and did `window.origin` and it printed out the stack overflow url.  I then did `window.origin = 'fake'`.  Typing `window.origin` again, resulted in `fake` logging to the console.  So that doesn't seem very secure.

Comment: @Taplar, so the idea is that it's not good enough because an XSS attack could derail the check?

Comment: If you can modify the value it checks against before it does the check, then the control is entirely within the attackers domain.

Comment: A better approach may be to have Page2 send a request to the server which will be authenticated at the server. And then have the server send whatever data that was contained in the request from Page 2 on to Page1 which has already been authenticated, using websockets  or some other technology. With this approach you only have handle auth at the server and not between pages. Much easier to maintain and secure as you can set CORS header, etc.

Comment: @CodyPace, thank you, that's a great suggestion! I am trying to balance the complexity here, so I'm not sure if I will go with websockets per se, but the general direction is helpful.

Comment: @CodyPace, @Taplar, hypothetically, what would you think about doing `window.location.href.startsWith(event.origin)`? It seems that window.location and its properties can't really be reassigned in practice.